# php: onClick event - table

Tags: php, mysql

How to use onclick in table?
The following code is my basic code.

**php code**

```
$con = mysqli_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_passwd,$db_name);
mysqli_set_charset($con, "utf8");

$result = mysqli_query($con, "select * from Marker_DB");

echo "<table border=’1′> <tr> <th>num</th> </tr>";

$n = 1;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>". $row['num'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
$n++;
}

echo "</table>";
mysqli_close($con);
```

I've made a lot of attempts to use onclick. Here's how I tried:

**code**

```
echo "<td>". "onclick='displayComment($row['num'])" . "</td>";

echo "<td onClick="'www.google.com/'">". $row['num'] . "</td>";
```

How can I use onclick in php?

Comment: What do you want to happen when you click the cell?

Comment: "onclick" is a Event Attribute so it will be use with HTML tag. like this <td onclick="myFunction()">

Comment: I have a suggestion to keep your code clean and simple.  Either use a template engine like smarty or for this specific problem a package like datatables. It will help you mixing javascript, html and php. Just a tip for further projects :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give your table some id,

```
echo "<table border='1′ id='table-id'> <tr> <th>num</th> </tr>";
```

Then your `td` will be as it is,

```
echo "<td>". $row['num'] . "</td>";
```

In js just write this code and check,

```
$("#table-id").on("click", "td", function() {
    alert($(this).text()); // see if you get the value of $row['num']
    // you can play here as you like
    var num = $(this).text();
    displayComment(num);
});

function displayComment(num) {
    // your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to stop the propagation of the parent event when a child is clicked, it's easy done in jQuery, but naively you need to do a little more work:

```
function displayComment(num){ 
    //Do your stuffs with num

    console.log('td clicked');
};
```

Note, for Firefox you need to pass a event parameter:

```
<td onclick="displayComment($row['num'])">Column 3</td>
```